# Awk losing posix mode under sudo

Tags: awk, sudo, gawk

This started as an obscure problem with RPM scriptlets occasionally failing on awk. I narrowed it down to the following: The scriptlets use a GNU extension: length(array) construct, not supported when running in the posix mode. OK so far. What I don't understand is how running awk under sudo changes the posix compliance behavior. Here is a simple awk script that should run in the GNU mode, and should fail in posix mode.

```
$ cat ./try
/bin/awk 'BEGIN{x[1]=foo;x[2]=bar;print length(x);}'
$ /bin/awk --version | grep Awk
GNU Awk 4.0.2
$ id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
$ /bin/sh ./try
awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: length: received array argument
$ sudo /bin/sh ./try
2
$
```

What is the underlying mechanism that changes the awk behavior?

Comment: I wouldn't call `length` on array "obsolete", it's a GNU extension to POSIX awk.

Comment: Do you have the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable set for the non-root user?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thanks, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Awk (really gawk under linux) is being controlled by the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable, which was  occasionally being inherited from the original user's environment. The installation in question must be run by root, but at times the admin would become root with "su" which keeps the environment, thus keeping his `POSIXLY_CORRECT`, forcing gawk into a posix mode, and failing the GNU length(array) extension. At other times the admin would run "sudo" or "su -" to become root, start with root's clean environment and successfully run the extended gawk functionality.

Comment: ...and if you want to find the length of an array in a POSIX way: `c=0; for (i in array) c++; print c`.